# Image quality gets low after cropping

Tags: android, image, camera, crop

I am capturing an image using camera intent and send it to server. But the problem is when i crop this image its quality is reduced to great extent. It looks weird. I am using Samsung note 2 for testing but image quality is too poor after cropping. Can any one please share a Good cropping code that does not reduces its quality? This is my current Code to Crop an image.

```
public void performCrop(Uri picUri) {
    try {
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/* ");
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {

        String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
        toast(errorMessage);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: solved? can u post solution?